# Map through new array then push items to objects in exisiting array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have one main array which exists like so.

```
arr = {
    people:[{name: 'Zero'},{name: 'Jeans'},{name: 'Duct'}]
}
```

And I want to map over an array of colors and assign each object in the array a color from this array.

```
colors = { color: ['#fff', '#fa0', '#eee'] }
```

How would this be achieved?

I can map through arr.people then map colors.color but no luck.

Would like to end up with this

```
 arr = {
    people:[{name: 'Zero', color: '#FFF'},
            {name: 'Jeans', color: '#FA0'},
            {name: 'Duct', color: '#EEE'}
           ]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `map`

```
arr.people = arr.people.map( (s, i) => ({...s, color: colors.color[i]}) )
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = {
  people: [{
    name: 'Zero'
  }, {
    name: 'Jeans'
  }, {
    name: 'Duct'
  }]
};
var colors = {
  color: ['#fff', '#fa0', '#eee']
};
arr.people = arr.people.map((s, i) => ({ ...s,
  color: colors.color[i]
}));

console.log(arr);
```

**Explanation**

- Iterate `arr.people` using `map`
- Return an object from each iteration having an extra property - `color` using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: Damn that looks so simple. Thank you

Comment: @mplungjan Sure